# How can i make element dragable which is in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some elemets which is dragable and dropable

you can check here - `*http://jsfiddle.net/Mf6zJ/269/*`

now when i have placed this dragable elements in table then these element cannot be dragable.

please check here - `*http://jsfiddle.net/Mf6zJ/271/*`

when user drag any element from this i want to check the postion of this element

so please suggest me to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

html

```
   <pre>
    <div id="info">Waiting for update</div>
    </pre>

    <ul id="test-list">
        <li id="listItem_1"><img src="arrow.png" alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" /><strong>Item 1 </strong></li>
      <li id="listItem_2"><img src="arrow.png" alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" /><strong>Item 2</strong></li>
      <li id="listItem_3"><img src="arrow.png" alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" /><strong>Item 3</strong></li>
        <li id="listItem_4"><img src="arrow.png" alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" /><strong>Item 4</strong></li>
    </ul>
```

css:

```
ul{
  list-style: none;
}

li{
  display: inline;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mf6zJ/274/)

Answer (score 0):

Your html isn't formatted correctly. Your code, try arranging it this way:

```
<pre>
<div id="info">Waiting for update</div>
</pre>
<table>
    <tr><td>
<ul id="test-list">
    <li id="listItem_1"><img src="arrow.png" alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" /><strong>Item 1 </strong></li>
  <li id="listItem_2"><img src="arrow.png" alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" /><strong>Item 2</strong></li>
  <li id="listItem_3"><img src="arrow.png" alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" /><strong>Item 3</strong></li>
    <li id="listItem_4"><img src="arrow.png" alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" /><strong>Item 4</strong></li>
</ul>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mf6zJ/273/)